# Is it important to include Advance level result in cv when you have post graduate diploma?

Tags: publications, phd, cv, education, social-media

I had successfully completed my post graduate diploma in TESOL after completing my IELTS. I have 12 years of experience in teaching. I have a plan to migrate to a country. Therefore I thought of making my cv standard. In my cv is it must to include my Advanced level result or completion? I’m worried that I couldn’t complete it and my colleagues are saying that I must include which is equivalent to advance level education. I’m bit confused what to do. Do I need to do foundation course now? I think it is not necessary bcs I’m a language teacher and I’m in my level 7 and why should I do level 3? I’m confused. Please help me.